# Instantiate contract from clone factory with value

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I'm currently trying to create instances of a smart contract via a clone factory. The problem is, that I'm not able to send a value to the init function of the smart contract I'm trying to instantiate. Here is a example:

TestContract.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >0.4.23 <0.9.0;

contract TestContract {
    string testmessage;

function init(
    string memory _testmessage
) public payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "The contract has to have at least a value");
    testmessage = _testmessage;
}
```

TestContractFactory.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >0.4.23 <0.9.0;
import "./TestContract.sol";
import "./CloneFactory.sol";

contract TestContractFactory is CloneFactory {
    address public testContractAddress;
    address[] public clonedTestContracts;

event TestContractCreated(address newTestContract);

constructor(address _testContractAddress)
{
    testContractAddress = _testContractAddress;
}


function createTestContractAddress(
    string memory testmessage
) public payable {
    address clone = createClone(testContractAddress);
    TestContract(clone).init(testmessage);
    clonedTestContracts.push(clone);
    emit TestContractCreated(clone);
}
```

}

So when I try to instantiate a TestContract via the Factory in Remix with the value of 1 Ether, I get the message "The contract has to have at least a value". Does someone know why this happens? I was only able to find examples that use normal factories and not clone factories.

Comment: I believe the answer to the above question will help you out. I assume in your testing you're sending ETH with the call to `createTestContractAddress`. You also need to send the ETH with the call to `init`, you can see how to do that in the answer to the above question. Let me know if you need more guidance

Comment: The answer in the question you provided was exactly what i needed. Thank you!